# how to change the Node of a TriplePath in Jena?

Tags: java, jena, apache-jena, arq

I want to change a node of a Jena TriplePath (org.apache.jena.sparql.core.TriplePath), but I haven't found any manner. Imagine I have this code:

```
TriplePath tp = null;
....
//tp has been defined and not null

Node domain = tp.getSubject();
Node predicate = tp.getPredicate();
Node range = tp.getObject();
Node newNode = NodeFactory.createURI("http://www.example.com/example/example");

//And now? How can I set a Node (domain/predicate/range) of tp?
```

The question is, how can I set any Node (domain/predicate/range) of the TriplePath tp with the newNode I've created? Is there any manner?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new path and assign it to `tp`.  `TriplePath`s are immutable, as is the rest of the SPARQL algebra in Jena (any ways to defeat this should not be used!).

For more complex setups, have a template with variables and use:

```
TriplePath Substitute.substitute(TriplePath triplePath, Binding binding)
```